# Ajax not displaying data on a web page in my Django app--and instead shows this >>> <cart.cart.Cart object at 0x0000014D574B3AD0>

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I'm following VeryAcademy's Django E commerce tutorial on YouTube and I encountered and issue.

I followed the tutorial precisely and reach the Ajax part where we pass the add_to_cart data to the cart page to be displayed--and instead of seeing the data--I see this

```
<cart.cart.Cart object at 0x0000014D574B3AD0>
```

what is this?

I'm supposed to see the product details of the current items in cart--not this.

Here is my Ajax code. I'm running Django:

```
    
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');



$(document).on('click', '#add_button', function (e) {
    
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{% url 'inventory:single_product_add_to_cart' %}",
        data: {
                productid: $('#add_button').val(),
                productqty: $('#select option:selected').text(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
                action: 'post'
                datatype: 'json',
        },
        success: function (json) {
            document.getElementById("basket-qty").innerHTML = json.qty
        },
            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {}
      });
    })
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for ds_mp project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os 
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-=11=m9jxo1py7x9o$!*0#8#$3*s38c3cd%2rtlf1x112n!2lnj'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    'django.contrib.sites',



    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.amazon',


    'ckeditor',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'localflavor',
    'mptt',
    'django_social_share',
    'django_filters',



]

SITE_ID = 1
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [

    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',


    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ds_mp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'inventory.views.inventory_categories',
                'catalog.views.catalog_categories',
                'ds_mp_app.views.front_page_categories',
                'vendors.views.top_vendors_menu',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ds_mp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache",
        "LOCATION": "/var/tmp/django_cache",
    }    
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'memberships:profile'






CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'

CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '127.0.0.1:8002'

SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrftoken'
#CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
#SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1209600

CART_SESSION_ID = "cart"
```

views.py

```
def single_product_add_to_cart(request):

    cart = Cart(request)
    
    if request.POST.get("action") == "post":
        product_id = int(request.POST.get("productid"))
        product_qty = int(request.POST.get("productqty"))
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)

        cart.add(product=product, qty=product_qty)

        cartqty = cart.__len__()
        response = JsonResponse({'qty': cartqty})
        
        return response
```

cart.py

```
from .models import Product
from django.conf import settings
from decimal import Decimal


class Cart:

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if settings.CART_SESSION_ID not in request.session:
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]={}
        self.cart = cart


    def add(self, product, qty):
        product_id = str(product.id)

        if product_id in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id]["qty"] = qty
        else:

            self.cart[product_id] = {"price":str(product.price_regular), "qty":qty}

        self.save()


    def update():
        pass 
    def delete():
        pass



    def __len__(self):
        return sum(item["qty"] for item in self.cart.values()) 


    def __iter__(self):
        
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        cart = self.cart.copy()

        for product in products:
            cart[str(product.id)]["product"] = product

        for item in cart.values():
            item["price"] = Decimal(item["price"])
            item["total_price"] = item["price"] * item["qty"]
            yield item



    def get_subtotal(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item["price"]) * item["qty"] for item in self.cart.values())


    def get_grand_total(self):
        newprice = 0.00 
        subtotal = sum(Decimal(item["price"]) * item["qty"] for item in self.cart.values()) 

        if "purchase" in self.session:
            pass 
        total = subtotal + Decimal(newprice)
        return total


    def clear():
        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        del self.session["address"]
        del self.session["purchase"]
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session.modified = True
```

I can't tell if this is a cookies/sessions issue, of the Ajax code, or the python.

What can you make of this?